# Can I delete my account from cortana

Tags: windows-10, cortana

I was just wondering about Cortana in Microsoft Windows 10. I came across the question "can I delete my Microsoft Account from Cortana?"

My question is: Can I delete my account and data from Cortana?

Comment: You can delete data from Cortana by requesting your Microsoft Account be deleted.

Comment: You can disable and remove your data from Cortana. If you want to know how then I'll provide you the steps to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Press the Cortana (circle) button, press the Notepad tab on the left of the Cortana panel that pops up, press settings, scroll down to the bottom and there are links to Microsoft pages where you can delete all of your Cortana data from their servers.